# How dangerous is it to verify my account with a photo of my visa, passport, or ID card?

Tags: privacy, identity-theft

In order to play poker online on some accounts you have to verify your age and identity. And to do that, I need to email the site with a picture of my visa or passport or ID card.

- How dangerous is it for me to send them a picture of the USA visa page in my passport?
- And how dangerous is is to send a picture of the passports first page or ID card?